# jQuery script ignores hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a basic bit of jQuery script on my web page that has div hide/show functionality.

It works great, however, I have noticed that my links inside the 'hidden' div (`.newboxes2`) do not work as expected. I expect to click them and get taken to Google.

Can someone explain how I update my code to fix this?

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fS5gq/5/) with hopefully illustrates my point.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('.showscroll').bind('click', 'h2, h3', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   $(this).toggleClass('active');
   $(".newboxes2").not($(this).find(".newboxes2")).slideUp();
   $(this).find('.newboxes2').slideToggle();

               if($(this).is('.active') ) {
                       $(this).find('img.small').attr('src', '/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/images/image_corner_btn_onstate.png');
               } else {
                       $(this).find('img.small').attr('src', '/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/images/image_corner_btn_offstate.png');
               }
   if (this.id === 'service29') {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(this).find('h2').offset().top
    }, 1000);
                }

 });

});
```

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `e.preventDefault();` in your jquery. this stops the link from going.

Comment: That is perfect. One final wee alteration. How do I stop the div from closing when the 'google' link is clicked?

Comment: The google link still doesn't work. Does jsFiddle stop external links?

Comment: Yes it stops external re-directions.

Comment: try encapsulating your link into a sibling of your targeted div.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this one :- http://jsfiddle.net/fS5gq/9/.

```
$(".ancClass").click(function (e) {
    window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");  
    return false;
});
```

I have added a class for the anchor tag and added event to handle the redirection.

Comment: That's brilliant, wiz kid! Sorry for my delay. Can you tell me how I stop the div from sliding up when the google link is clicked?

Comment: Sliding up will not happen as the anchor returns false on click. Try out the fiddle, it's working fine.